# JRE System Library 1.3.1_20 notify an error on OracleDataSource Usage

Tags: unix, version, java

### Java -version (Sco Openserver 5)

`Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build SCO-UNIX-J2SE-1.3.1_22:*
FCS*:20080305)
Classic VM (build SCO-UNIX-J2SE-1.3.1_22:*FCS*:20080305, green threads, sunwjit)`

Problem :
`OracleDataSource ods = OracleDatasource();`

It occurs error :

**The type javax.sql.DataSource cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .
 class files**

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a wrong driver. Your driver requires java 1.4.

The javax.sql.DataSource has been added with java 1.4.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html

Make sure that you are using a JDBC driver that supports java 1.3.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-10201-088211.html the classes12.jar should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This means that your program is missing a library on the class path.

You must make sure that, for example, when you export a compiled jar file, that you export the libraries along with it ...

Of course.... I'm assuming you were able to compile your program correctly.

Comment: jayunit100: i'm not able to compile source code due to **OracleDatasource** is not available to work . I already added oraclejdbc driver . So i think it's not a problem with oracle driver.